# blocked by cors policy when connecting node js service

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

When I am trying to connect Nodejs service (deployed in server) from the Angular (my local machine) throwing CORS policy error.

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxxxxxx.xxxx.net:3500/api/get' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy.
    
    I have added the below code in node side to enable the headers before the routes are defined, but still, it's not working.
```

`const CORSOrigin = ['http://localhost:3000']

```
            app.use(
              cors((req, callback) => {
                const options = {
                  credentials: true,
                  origin: CORSOrigin,
                };
                callback(null, options);
              })
            );`
```

Any thought?

Comment: Can you share Angular code too? Angular port is 3000, express is 3500 correct?
And what is "/api/get" code of express? More detailed information easy to get an answer from community.

Answer (score 0):

if you are tesing the API you can use chrome extensions to bypass CORS policy....
I use CORS Unblock and it work fine as I dont have access to server side

Answer (score -1):

If it's for the sake of testing try a [cors unblock](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino)

If you are trying to setup CORS try testing through a tunneling tool like ngrok.